# Trouble installing Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error when trying to install Rails 4 after having installed RVM & Ruby 2

MacBook-Pro:~ Jihun$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Fetching: rake-10.1.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
MacBook-Pro:~ Jihun$ rails --version
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231798/installing-rails-4-0 follow up the link, it may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

I think you haven't set it yet. You might have to run

```
rvm 2.0.0@rails-4.0
```

instead though to specify rails 4.0 precisely.