# Rails 4 bundler: command not found: rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am guessing that this answer has been already answered somewhere but I was not able to find it. I am having troubles with installing `Rails 4`. I have put in the `Gemfile`:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
```

And I have run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` and all the gems are installed, but when I run `bundle exec rails s` then I receive an error:

```
bundler: command not found: rails
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

`which rails` doesn't returning anything. I am using `ruby 2.0.0` and `rvm` and it seems everything has been set up.

What am I missing and how to set-up Rails 4?

Comment: can you execute **gem install rails** directly in the console?

Here is a link with the answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231798/installing-rails-4-0)

Comment: yes I can. As a matter of a fact, I was able to use Rails 4 when I create a new gemset for rvm and install manually gem like that, but in that case I would need to switch gemset everytime I change project, which in a way I want to avoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What solved my problem for Rails 4, in this case,  was running a command in the root directory of the application:

```
bundle exec rake rails:update:bin
```

After that , running a `bundle exec rails s` reported no errors and was working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In Gemfile please add

```
ruby 2.0.0
```

or

Try to use `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset`.

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708916/use-rvmrc-or-ruby-version-file-to-set-a-project-gemset-with-rvm#answers)